# Logistic regression for probability of action in next n days

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, logistic, python, scikit-learn

I've built a Logistic Regression model in Python for the likelihood of an individual doing an action *in the next n days*. I am not very experienced at this!

My data comprises one row per individual. I have >500k individuals. I have five individual-level features, and a sixth time-based feature: median gap between actions.

I've built a model with a test F1 score >0.95. **My question**: is this sufficient to predict individuals doing this action in the next n days -- or am I accidentally classifying them according to whether they'll do this at all?

Comment: Regarding your measured outcome variable (the $y$), what does it measure?

Comment: Whether the individual has done the action in the "next" n days -- i.e. when wrangling the data I calculated it based on n days ago, then y is where they did it between n days ago and today.